# Action and reaction in case of a falling object

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

Let us say a hard object is falling on a stack of pillows. At the point of contact, it will experience a force equal to its weight and would be at rest if it were not for the fact that the stack of pillows starts getting compressed because of the extra weight and takes the object with it. The stack will keep getting compressed till it has enough force for resistance. This force of resistance must equal the weight of the body to prevent the body from falling further. If it is at this point that the body provides enough force to equal the weight of the body, then how could the stack offer an upward force on the body (reaction) to match the weight of the body (action) at the point of contact?

Answer (score 1):

1. at all points of contact the force from the falling weight is not equal to its weight but equal to its deceleration multiplied by its mass--Newton's second law.
2. the force provided by the pillow is almost never equal to the force exerted by the weight--the forces are equal only at the end of the compression, when the weight is at rest.
3. the force provided by the pillow varies on how much it is already compressed. analagous to a spring, it's return force is proportional to its compression--Hooke's law. the pillow cannot match any force until it has compressed by an amount, and will compress until it can do so, and stay under compression equal to the weight of the now stationary fallen object.

Comment: What I meant was the following:1. Force due to the body is always the weight of the body. If we draw a free body diagram of the pillows,  we will have mg(weight of the body) + weight of the pilow itself = mass of the pillow x accelaration of the pillow. For the body we will have mg - upward force exerted by the pillow = ma.

Comment: That is not the case.  At the moment of contact, the body exerts the smallest imaginable force on the pillow, and the pillow exerts the same force back on the body.  There are other forces acting on the body and pillows, and these help to determine the accelerations, but Neton's Third Law is ***always*** true...

Comment: was referring to the net force. it is never equal as long as the pillow/weight has acceleration. this was to clear the misunderstanding that the object exerts its weight on the pillow at the point of contact, which is not true.

Comment: I would like to side with User58220 in that Newton's third law is always true. Let us take the case of a horizontal case (to avoid the effect of gravity). If I apply a force on the pillow/spring using a body that is already accelerating at a constant rate, I suppose you are saying that the pillow/spring experiences an infinitely small force at the point of contact. You are also suggesting that this force experienced by the pillow/spring increases as the force compresses the body. The deceleration x mass at any instant represents the force that is not yet felt and matched by the reaction.

Comment: The moral of the story seems to be that a body does not experience all the force at once but slowly as the force acts against the body and compresses it. What happens in case of solid bodies then that are able to stop the body almost instantaneously (or reverse its direction of acceleration)? Are they experiencing the whole force at once? How come?